# What is the relation between elementarily equivalent structures and $\Delta$-elementrary class of structures?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

In first order logic, from Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic [VI.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA91) on p91, definition of $\Delta$-elementary class of structures:

> For a set $\Phi$  of $S$-sentences we call  $$ Mod^S \Phi  :=
>  \{\mathfrak{A}\text{ | $\mathfrak{A}$  is an $S$-structure and
>  $\mathfrak{A} \models \Phi$} \} $$ the class  of models of $\Phi$.
>
> 3.1 Definition.  Let $\mathfrak{R}$ be a class of $S$-structures.
>
> (a)  $\mathfrak{R}$ is called elementary if there is an $S$-sentence $\phi$
> such that $\mathfrak{R} =  Mod^S \phi$.
>
> (b)  $\mathfrak{R}$ is  called $\Delta$-elementary if there is  a  set
> $\Phi$  of $S$-sentences such that $\mathfrak{R} =  Mod^S \Phi$

and from VI.4 on [p94](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA94), definition of elementarily equivalent structures

> 4.1  Definition.  (a)  Two  $S$-structures $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ are  called  elementarily  equivalent  (written:
> $\mathfrak{A} \equiv \mathfrak{B}$) if for every $S$-sentence $\phi$
> we have $\mathfrak{A} \models \phi$ iff $\mathfrak{B} \models \phi$ .
>
> (b)  For an $S$-structure $\mathfrak{A}$, let $Th(\mathfrak{A}) := \{\phi \text{ is a $S$-sentence | $ \mathfrak{A} \models \phi$}\}$ .
> $Th(\mathfrak{A})$ is called  the (first-order)  theory of
> $\mathfrak{A}$.
>
> 4.2 Lemma.  For two $S$-structures $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$,  $\mathfrak{B} \equiv \mathfrak{A}$ iff $\mathfrak{B} \models Th(\mathfrak{A})$.

and on [p95](https://books.google.com/books?id=4sbSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA95), relation between the two concepts:

> 4.3 Theorem.   (b)  For every structure $\mathfrak{A}$ ,  the  class $\{\mathfrak{B} \text{ | $\mathfrak{B} \equiv \mathfrak{A}$ }\}$  is
> $\Delta$-elementary; in fact  $\{\mathfrak{B} \text{ | $\mathfrak{B} \equiv \mathfrak{A}$ }\}  =  Mod^S  Th(\mathfrak{A})$.  Moreover,
> $\{\mathfrak{B} \text{ | $\mathfrak{B} \equiv \mathfrak{A}$ }\}$  is
> the smallest $\Delta$-elementary class which  contains $\mathfrak{A}$.
>
> 4.3(b)  shows that a  $\Delta$-elementary class contains, together with any given structure, all elementarily equivalent ones.

- Is it correct that $Mod^S(\Phi)$ may contain $S$-structures which satisfy formulas in $\Phi$ and might further satisfy formulas outside $\Phi$?
- In 4.1 Definition (a), is it correct that $\mathfrak{A} \equiv \mathfrak{B}$ iff the two structures have the same theory i.e. $Th(\mathfrak{A}) = Th(\mathfrak{B})$?
- Does 4.2 Lemma say that $\mathfrak{B} \equiv \mathfrak{A}$ iff  $Th(\mathfrak{A}) \subseteq Th(\mathfrak{B})$? (Is that equivalent to $Th(\mathfrak{A}) = Th(\mathfrak{B})$?)
- In 4.3. Theorem (b), in $\{\mathfrak{B} \text{ | $\mathfrak{B} \equiv \mathfrak{A}$ }\}  =  Mod^S  Th(\mathfrak{A})$, the LHS is the set of $\mathfrak{B}$ s.t. $Th(\mathfrak{A}) = Th(\mathfrak{B})$, and the RHS is set of $\mathfrak{B}$ s.t. $Th(\mathfrak{A}) \subseteq Th(\mathfrak{B})$?
- Is a  minimal $\Delta$-elementary class  exactly either one elementarily equivalent class, or  the union of several  elementarily equivalent classes? (In other words, an elementarily equivalent class can be partially in a minimal  $\Delta$-elementary class?)

The last two are my main questions, which gives me a contradiction, possible due to my misunderstanding of relevant concepts as in the first three questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order:

- Yes. There are no *negative* requirements in the definition of $Mod^S(\Phi)$ - although of course we have $$\varphi\in\Phi, \mathfrak{M}\in Mod^S(\Phi)\quad\implies\quad \mathfrak{M}\not\models\neg\varphi.$$
- Yes, that's correct, basically by definition.
- Yes, if $Th(\mathfrak{A})\subseteq Th(\mathfrak{B})$ then $Th(\mathfrak{A})=Th(\mathfrak{B})$. This is due to the nature of negation, and in particular the fact that for every $\mathfrak{C},\varphi$ we have $$\varphi\not\in Th(\mathfrak{C})\quad\iff\neg\varphi\in Th(\mathfrak{C}).$$ Consequently, if $\varphi\in Th(\mathfrak{B})\setminus Th(\mathfrak{A})$ then $\neg\varphi\in Th(\mathfrak{A})\setminus Th(\mathfrak{B})$.
- Yes.
- A minimal $\Delta$-elementary class is exactly the same thing as an elementary equivalence class. The situation I think you're describing, where a minimal $\Delta$-elementary class overlaps with multiple distinct elementary equivalence classes, cannot occur.

Comment: Thanks.  What possible cases can be for the relation between Δ-elementary classes (not necessarily minimal) and  elementary equivalence classes?

Comment: @Tim Well, every $\Delta$-elementary class is a union of elementary equivalence classes; the converse fails, though (this is a good exercise).

Comment: What is "the converse "?

Comment: @Tim Noah's statement is: If $C$ is a $\Delta$-elementary class, then $C$ is a union of elementary equivalence classes. The converse of this statement is: If $C$ is a union of elementary equivalence classes, then $C$ is a $\Delta$-elementary class.

Comment: @Tim As a hint for that exercise - as Alex says, to prove that there is a union of elementary equivalence classes which is *not* a $\Delta$-elementary class - work in the empty language and consider the (classes of models associated to the) theories $T_n$, where $T_n$ is the full theory of an $n$-element set (remember that since our language is empty, a structure is just a set).